# How can I test that a AlertDialog appeared?

Tags: flutter

Hello I have a window with a button that should open an AlertDialog. How can I build a test that tells me that the alert opened?

```
var button = find.byKey(KEY_ADD_WALLET);
await tester.tap(button);

expect(... ??? ...)
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer myself:

```
var button = find.byKey(KEY_ADD_WALLET);
await tester.tap(button);
await tester.pumpAndSettle();
expect(find.byType(Dialog), findsOneWidget);
```

The magic is calling tester.pumpAndSettle();

A more specific test could be:

```
expect(find.descendant(of: find.byType(Dialog), matching: find.text("Add public wallet")),findsOneWidget);
```